# Google Apps Marketplace SDK install does not forward user to Setup URL

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have an application that was previously working when installed from the Google Apps Marketplace SDK. For some reason things are behaving differently now.

Before a user would click install, grant permissions, and be redirected to the Setup URL specified (i.e `http://localhost:12345/setup/${DOMAIN_NAME}`). This used to work just fine.

Now when a user clicks install they are asked which domain to install it on (like before), they consent, but no redirect takes place. When the user confirms the install a window stating that the app needs to be installed comes up but quickly disappears before the user can click 'Continue'. This is where redirect would normally have happened. A small window appears confirming the setup of the application on the domain and where users can find it. 
It has a 'Launch App' button that when clicked redirects to the global login URL but the domain param is incorrect as it is just passing `http://localhost:12345/a/$%7BDOMAIN_NAME%7D` which is a URL encoded parameter of "${DOMAIN_NAME}".

This is also happening live on the Chrome Web Store.

Any ideas?

Comment: @jonathanberi Can you assist with this? It seems to be acting akwardly. Google documentation says to post here.

Comment: @jonathanberi Thanks. Do I have to specify anything in the manifest? It seems that my latest manifest has put our app in the Google Apps Marketplace but I can't search for it. I'm a bit confused with the "new" marketplace.

Comment: I should have asked - is this on the old store or the new? You should only have to set the URL in your Google APIs project.

Comment: @jonathanberi The new one. Just checking on the manifest.

Comment: Is your app published? I'd like to take a look and see what might be going on.

Comment: It is but was just removed. I need the setup process to test the changes to be made. Can we take this to email as it contains information I don't wish to publish?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46860/discussion-between-jonathanberi-and-aleckz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed that this was a bug on our side and the fix should role out tomorrow morning PST.

Comment: Was this fixed?  I'm having the same issue.  Setup Url doesn't seem to do anything.  Same with the Admin Config Url.

Comment: For anyone who finds this...the Url has to end in .com, localhost doesn't work.

Comment: We have the same issue. Any news on a bug fix?

Comment: I believe this is the way it is going forward. It's been like this for quite a while. @jonathanberi, any update?